# how to free memory on fragments onDestroyView()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a widget, which opens a Fragment showing a list of contacts with their pictures. This Fragment consumes a lot of memory. On leaving the Fragment, the memory is still allocated...

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {

         final List<BWContact> contacts = ContactHandler.getByGroup(group);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new BWContactAdapter(getActivity(), contacts, true));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ...
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();

    }
}
```

How can I tell the fragment to free the memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand this line:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
```

Is your list attached to the activity? In this case, yes the activity will retain the listView with all the contacts.